# c++ program display number

Tags: c++, modulo

write a program that displays numbers from 1 to 100 like this

*if number is divisible by 3 then it displays aaa 
*if number is divisible by 5 then it displays bbb 
*if number is divisible by 3 and 5 then it displays ccc 
*else display number

*each number must be displayed on single line

How can i do this in c++? so far I've written this but it doesn't work as expected

```
 for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
{
    if(i%3==0)
        cout<<"aaa"<<endl;
    if(i%5==0)
        cout<<"bbb"<<endl;
    if(i%3==0 && i%5==0)
        cout<<"ccc"<<endl;
    else
    {
        cout<<i<<endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: well it displays 1 2 aaa 3 4 bbb 5 aaa 6 7 8 aaa 9 bbb 10 11 aaa 12 13 14 aaa bbb ccc 15 16...etc

Comment: You should check `if(i%3==0 && i%5==0)` first, then `else if(i%3==0)` and `else if(i%5==0)`.

Comment: You are likely missing some `else`. But as a learning experience, I'm not telling you where...

Comment: when you get it working, you should be able to pass *any* interview....

Comment: right...10x anderas...but why was a mistake if I didn't use the else statements? I mean..if the condition from my first statement isn't executed then it passes to the next one and evaluates it and so on. Why was is necessary to use the else statements?

Comment: @AnaProdan Just imagine that you are the computer executing your code. What happens if the condition inside the first `if` is true? The `cout` is executed and it goes on at the line after that. In that case, do you really want to execute the next `if`-statement?

Comment: ok. 10x for the reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use some original approach then you can write the program the following way.:)

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    for ( int i = 1; i <= 100; i++ )
    {
        unsigned mask = ( i % 3 == 0 ) + ( ( i % 5 == 0 ) << 1 );

        switch ( mask )
        {
        case 1:             
            std::cout << "aaa";
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "bbb";
            break;
        case 3:
            std::cout << "ccc";
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << i;
            break;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For example if to use the range [1, 15] instead of [1,100] then the output will be

```
1
2
aaa
4
bbb
aaa
7
8
aaa
bbb
11
aaa
13
14
ccc
```

Or you can even introduce an enumeration for readability. For example

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    enum { NONE = 0, AAA = 1, BBB = 2, CCC = AAA + BBB };

    for ( int i = 1; i <= 100; i++ )
    {
        //                   AAA       +         BBB             
        unsigned mask = ( i % 3 == 0 ) + ( ( i % 5 == 0 ) << 1 );

        switch ( mask )
        {
        case AAA:               
            std::cout << "aaa";
            break;
        case BBB:
            std::cout << "bbb";
            break;
        case CCC:
            std::cout << "ccc";
            break;
        default:    //  NONE
            std::cout << i;
            break;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If it is a school assignment then I assure you that nobody will present the solution I showed. You will be the only who will present such a solution.:)

Answer (score 0):

the second and third "if" should be "else if", 
otherwise they are disconnected if-structures, meaning the if statements are seen as separate bits of code that do not know about eachother - each if is evaluated every time.
So also the last if is evaluated every time, meaning that the last "else" will be done more often than you expected and print the number every time

furthermore, the third if should be the first one, to avoid multiple letter prints (the aaa bbb ccc stuff)

Comment: right..I managed to fix that 10x. But why was a mistake if I didn't use the else statements? I mean..if the condition from my first statement isn't executed then it passes to the next one and evaluates it and so on. Why was is necessary to use the else statements?

Comment: @AnaProdan : consecutive if statements are disconnected - whether or not the first if passes, you will always evaluate the second if, and so on... the "else" connects the if statements into one structure, that knows that if one passes, the others do not have to be evaluated

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you expect:

```
for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
{
  if(i%3==0 && i%5==0)
    cout<<"ccc"<<endl;
  else if(i%3==0)
    cout<<"aaa"<<endl;
  else if(i%5==0)
    cout<<"bbb"<<endl;
  else
  {
    cout<<i<<endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are many choices and we only choose one, we often write `if-else` nested statements:

```
if(i%3==0 && i%5==0)
    cout<<"ccc"<<endl;
else if(i%3==0)
    cout<<"aaa"<<endl;
else if(i%5==0)
    cout<<"bbb"<<endl;
else
    cout<<i<<endl;
```

If you can't figure out what's `else if` statement, that's combined with `else` and `if`:

```
if(i%3==0 && i%5==0)
{
    cout<<"ccc"<<endl;
}
else
{
    if(i%3==0)
    {
        cout<<"aaa"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if(i%5==0)
        {
            cout<<"bbb"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<i<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```